# In asp.net , how to get label Id from radgrid itemTemplate in GridEditableItem?

Tags: telerik-grid, radgrid

[image]

- Label1 do not get any values
- Out Like 
  [image]

Comment: Your issue was resolved?

Comment: yes , i am using different way so.. thanks